# Testing flow using prisma and graphql

Tags: testing, jestjs, graphql, prisma

I'm using prisma-graphql for backend server, and jest & supertest for testing graphql queries.
For testing environment, I'd like to establish an in-memory database to create and retrieve data during test-phase. My questions are,

1. What is a good way to configure a test DB for prisma client? Do I need to configure a memory DB at **before all** phase? like below?

   ```
   //setup.js for test

   beforeAll(async() => {
     db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:', (err) => {
       if (err) {
         return console.error(err.message);
       }
       console.log('Connected to the in-memory SQlite database.');
     });
   })
   ```
2. How & when can I run the commands for prisma? For instance, I need to run the below commands for in memory db, to create tables. https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/732 seems to suggest that in memory migration doesn't make sense - in other words, it does not support such thing?

   ```
   npx prisma migrate --experimental save/up
   npx prisma generate
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest going for integration tests against an actual DB as they will be a good way to test your code against the Queries/Mutations that you perform.

I have created a repo [here](https://github.com/ryands17/nexus-auth) that performs integration tests against an actual DB and this one is for GraphQL. These contain the entire Jest setup from start to finish.

Comment: Thanks. About PrismaTestEnvironment, are you making a test DB programmatically for testing Graphql resolvers?

Comment: Also, is there any way that I can set database provider also with an environment variable?

Comment: Yes I'm making a test DB automatically for that for every test suite. As for your second question, it's not possible to pass the database provider via an environment variable, but you can pass multiple providers using [this](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-schema/data-sources/#multiple-providers)

Comment: Thanks for answering. One more, do you have any idea what might have gone wrong if it says 'the table ~~ does not exist in the current database' when running test? The test code works well in my local configuration, but in EC2 it fails with saying the tables aren't correctly made.. I firstly doubted the npm migrate up --experimental wasn't working, but when I execute it manually it works fine. Clueless as to what is wrong (I checked file permissions, deleted whole node modules and reinstalled, executed in different directories and etc..)

Comment: I figured it out. Strangely, I have to execute migrate save first and then migrate up to reflect schema to the sqlite DB.. any idea why this would be the case?

Comment: Migrate save is not required as the migrations are already made on your system. Just `migrate up` is needed to add all the tables to the DB. You can clone my repo and run that as well and compare it with your implementation.